# Self-adjusting random walk

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, random-walks

> Let $X_t$ be a random process such that
>   \begin{eqnarray}
> X_1 &=& 0\\
> X_t &=& X_{t-1} + \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
> A_t, & X_{t-1} \geq 0\\
> B_t, & X_{t-1} < 0
> \end{array}\right.
> \end{eqnarray}
>   where $A_t$ and $B_t$ are i.i.d. random variables with the properties
>   \begin{eqnarray}
> E[A_t] &=& {-}\alpha ,& \text{Var}[A_t] &= \sigma^2\\
> E[B_t] &=& \alpha ,& \text{Var}[B_t] &= \sigma^2.
> \end{eqnarray}
>   **Question:** I am looking for techniques to establish an upper bound on $E[|X_t|]$ or $E[X_t^2]$ which holds for all $t\in\mathbb{N}$ in terms of $\alpha$ and $\sigma$.

I can write out $E[X_t^2]$ as follows
\begin{align}
E[X_t^2] &= E\left[(X_{t-1}+1_{X_{t-1}\geq 0}A_t+1_{X_{t-1}<0}B_t)^2\right]\\
 &= E[X_{t-1}^2] + E\left[(1_{X_{t-1}\geq 0}A_t+1_{X_{t-1}<0}B_t)^2\right] + 2 E\left[X_{t-1}(1_{X_{t-1}\geq 0}A_t+1_{X_{t-1}<0}B_t)\right]\\
&= E[X_{t-1}^2] + \alpha^2 + \sigma^2 - 2 E[|X_{t-1}|]\alpha
\end{align}
where $1_{\text{condition}}$ is the indicator function and the independence of $X_{t-1}$ and $A_t,B_t$ is used in the last equality.
For the case $\sigma>0$ and by assuming that $X_{t-1}$ and $X_t$ are identically distributed in the limit $t\rightarrow \infty$, we have $E[X_t^2] = E[X_{t-1}^2]$. Hence,
\begin{align}
\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}E[|X_t|] = \frac{\alpha^2+\sigma^2}{2\alpha}.
\end{align}

In the case $\sigma= 0$, we have $X_t = -\alpha$ for even $t$ and $X_t = 0$ for odd $t$. Thus, $E[|X_t|] \leq \alpha = \frac{\alpha^2+\sigma^2}{\alpha}$.

This leads me to the conjecture: $E[|X_t|] \leq \frac{\alpha^2+\sigma^2}{\alpha}$ for all t.

I am also interested in the rate of convergence to the limit $\frac{\alpha^2+\sigma^2}{2\alpha}$ if anything can be said about that?

Comment: Maybe this article is helpful: [The oscillating random walk](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304414974900106)

Comment: Still interested in a solution to this ?